# When creating an rpm package, how can I retain the permissions same as that of the source directory I have provided?

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

My source directory that gets packaged has different permissions for some directories and files, do I have to explicitly use %attr for each directory and file? Is there a way to just use same permissions as the source?

Relevant spec file sections:

```
%install 
cp -rp $RPM_BUILD_DIR/%{name}-%{version}/opt $RPM_BUILD_ROOT 
cp -rp $RPM_BUILD_DIR/%{name}-%{version}/var $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
```

and the %file section is:

```
%files 
/opt 
/var
```

EDIT:
SOLUTION (thanks to Chris Maes)
use %defattr(-,-,-)

Comment: If you have your solution, you don't need to edit your question, you should just accept the answer that solves your problem (checkbox on the left of the answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in that case, just use a dash (`-`):

```
%files
%defattr(-, user, group)
/path/to/files
```

from the [documentation](http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-files-list-directives.html):

> If a particular attribute does not need to be specified (usually because the file is installed with that attribute set properly), then that attribute may be replaced with a dash.

Comment: Thank you for responding, I used %attr(-,bin,bin) and then the list of files, but they are all still owned by root,root. In my source directory (root/rpmbuild/SOURCES) the permissions are correct(some files are root, some are bin) but when the rpm is created, everything is defaulted to root. Apologies if this is something basic, but im struggling to correct this.

Comment: in that case please post the (relevant) contents of your spec file.

Comment: im in the learning process so just simple file, copying the source to buildroot.
%install
                     cp -rp $RPM_BUILD_DIR/%{name}-%{version}/opt $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
                     cp -rp $RPM_BUILD_DIR/%{name}-%{version}/var $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
                    
and the %file section is:
%files
/opt
/var

Comment: Could you please add that to your question in a readable way? Also, I don't see the `%attr` part?

Comment: Oh my bad also: it needs to be `%defattr` to define the new defaults for all the following lines. I changed my answer.

Comment: May I ask what is the difference in behaviour when using %defattr vs %attr ? and what if we do not provide any of those parameters?

Comment: `%attr` is just for that line, for example: `%attr(-, nginx, nginx) /path/to/nginx/config`. with `%defattr` (on a separate line), you set new default values for all the following lines (which don't use `%attr`)

Comment: If you don't use any parameters, you'll use the default values, but I fail to find the default values. I think they are `(644, root, root, 755)` or `(-, root, root, 755)` or something like that.

Comment: Thank you, will try not to drag along the comments here too far. What I understand is that rpm does not retain the permissions of what is in the source dir and defaults it to some certain values (I see root,root) and you either need to use the defattr or attr to define the file ownerships.

Comment: Yes and no. If you specify `%defattr(-, -, -, -)`, `rpm` should then retain exactly your file permissions and ownerships.

Comment: Yes, I did so and it worked! Thank you SO MUCH!! :)

Comment: Sounds like you're building the RPMs as root? **Do not do that** - a poorly written specfile can *easily* destroy your machine.

Comment: @aaron I think you have seen more than one of my answers here, I have enough `rpm` experience to know that. I never build my rpms as root. Root just happens to be the default owner set by rpm, which is quite logical: it is the only user that is present anywhere ...

Comment: @ChrisMaes that wasn't directed at you, sorry.

Comment: @aaron no problem. It is difficult to include some nuance or wink in a comment. I totally agree with your remark. Thanks.